# How to add shadow to SVG <path>?

Tags: css, svg

I would like to create a simple shadow effect for some paths in SVG generated from a library. I have effectively used `<feDropShadow>` to add a shadow to other SVG elements like `<rect>`, but applying the same to a `<path>` either seems to make it disappear or has no effect.

For reference, here is the simple filter I am using:

```
<filter id="${id}">
  <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0"
  flood-color="${color}" />
</filter>
```

I then select the relevent SVG element and append this to its style attribute: `filter: url(#filter-id)`.

As mentioned previously, this works fine when applied to a `<rect>`, but not to a `<path>`. Also just for reference, what I am trying to achieve is to make a specific part of the SVG graphic "glow" to signify it being selected. I'l also mention that my target browser is google chrome, since browsers seem to vary quite a bit in their implementation of the SVG spec.

If someone can help me figure out how to achieve the desired effect for  I would greatly appreciate it!

Edit: I realize it would probably help if I included the SVG in question, since the most useful answer I've gotten doesn't seem to work for it. I wish I could provide a more minimal example, but this is about the most minimal I can manage. To provide context for it,all of the SVG is generated in the page dynamically using the mermaid-js library, except the two filters I append to the  inner HTML, which should be used to "highlight" relevant parts of the svg as events are triggered on the web page. I apply these filters to the relevant elements by appending `filter: url(#filter-id)` to its style attribute. This does work for when I apply it to a  that contains a , but doesn't when I apply it to a  that contains a  or if I apply it directly to the  in question.

In the snippet, one of the nodes in the graph is highlighted successfully, represented by the  with id "flowchart-a-14". The filter is also applied to the arrow going between the alpha and bravo node, which is represented by the  with id "L-a-b", which instead of being highlighted, disappears.

Note 1: the behavior is using google chrome, which is the target browser.
note 2: can't seem to include a runnable snippet. The button for bringing up the snippet editor doesn't appear for me.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mermaid-access-0" width="100%" height="50.720001220703125" style="max-width: 350.6000061035156px;" viewBox="0 0 350.6000061035156 50.720001220703125">
  <style>#mermaid-access-0{font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;fill:#333;}#mermaid-access-0 .error-icon{fill:#552222;}#mermaid-access-0 .error-text{fill:#552222;stroke:#552222;}#mermaid-access-0 .edge-thickness-normal{stroke-width:2px;}#mermaid-access-0 .edge-thickness-thick{stroke-width:3.5px;}#mermaid-access-0 .edge-pattern-solid{stroke-dasharray:0;}#mermaid-access-0 .edge-pattern-dashed{stroke-dasharray:3;}#mermaid-access-0 .edge-pattern-dotted{stroke-dasharray:2;}#mermaid-access-0 .marker{fill:#333333;}#mermaid-access-0 .marker.cross{stroke:#333333;}#mermaid-access-0 svg{font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;}#mermaid-access-0 .label{font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;color:#333;}#mermaid-access-0 .label text{fill:#333;}#mermaid-access-0 .node rect,#mermaid-access-0 .node circle,#mermaid-access-0 .node ellipse,#mermaid-access-0 .node polygon,#mermaid-access-0 .node path{fill:#ECECFF;stroke:#9370DB;stroke-width:1px;}#mermaid-access-0 .node .label{text-align:center;}#mermaid-access-0 .node.clickable{cursor:pointer;}#mermaid-access-0 .arrowheadPath{fill:#333333;}#mermaid-access-0 .edgePath .path{stroke:#333333;stroke-width:1.5px;}#mermaid-access-0 .flowchart-link{stroke:#333333;fill:none;}#mermaid-access-0 .edgeLabel{background-color:#e8e8e8;text-align:center;}#mermaid-access-0 .edgeLabel rect{opacity:0.5;background-color:#e8e8e8;fill:#e8e8e8;}#mermaid-access-0 .cluster rect{fill:#ffffde;stroke:#aaaa33;stroke-width:1px;}#mermaid-access-0 .cluster text{fill:#333;}#mermaid-access-0 div.mermaidTooltip{position:absolute;text-align:center;max-width:200px;padding:2px;font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;background:hsl(80,100%,96.2745098039%);border:1px solid #aaaa33;border-radius:2px;pointer-events:none;z-index:100;}#mermaid-access-0:root{--mermaid-font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;}#mermaid-access-0 flowchart{fill:apa;}</style>
  <g>
    <g class="output">
      <g class="clusters"/>
      <g class="edgePaths">
        <g class="edgePath LS-a LE-b" id="L-a-b" style="opacity: 1;filter:url(#mermaid-access-highlight-secondary);">
          <path class="path" d="M59.349998474121094,25.360000610351562L102.30999946594238,25.360000610351562L145.27000045776367,25.360000610351562" marker-end="url(#arrowhead14)" style="fill:none"/>
          <defs>
            <marker id="arrowhead14" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="9" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
              <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" class="arrowheadPath" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: 1, 0;"/>
            </marker>
          </defs>
        </g>
        <g class="edgePath LS-b LE-c" id="L-b-c" style="opacity: 1;">
          <path class="path" d="M197.2400016784668,25.360000610351562L240.2000026702881,25.360000610351562L283.1600036621094,25.360000610351562" marker-end="url(#arrowhead15)" style="fill:none"/>
          <defs>
            <marker id="arrowhead15" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="9" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
              <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" class="arrowheadPath" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: 1, 0;"/>
            </marker>
          </defs>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="edgeLabels">
        <g class="edgeLabel" transform="translate(102.30999946594238,25.360000610351562)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <g transform="translate(-17.96000099182129,-7.360000133514404)" class="label">
            <rect rx="0" ry="0" width="35.92000198364258" height="14.720000267028809"/>
            <foreignObject width="44.900001525878906" height="18.399999618530273">
              <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">
                <span id="L-L-a-b" class="edgeLabel L-LS-a' L-LE-b">Step 1</span>
              </div>
            </foreignObject>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g class="edgeLabel" transform="translate(240.2000026702881,25.360000610351562)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <g transform="translate(-17.96000099182129,-7.360000133514404)" class="label">
            <rect rx="0" ry="0" width="35.92000198364258" height="14.720000267028809"/>
            <foreignObject width="44.900001525878906" height="18.399999618530273">
              <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">
                <span id="L-L-b-c" class="edgeLabel L-LS-b' L-LE-c">Step 2</span>
              </div>
            </foreignObject>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="nodes">
        <g class="node default" id="flowchart-a-14" transform="translate(33.67499923706055,25.360000610351562)" style="opacity: 1;filter:url(#mermaid-access-highlight-primary);">
          <rect rx="0" ry="0" x="-25.675000190734863" y="-17.360000133514404" width="51.35000038146973" height="34.72000026702881" class="label-container"/>
          <g class="label" transform="translate(0,0)">
            <g transform="translate(-15.675000190734863,-7.360000133514404)">
              <foreignObject width="39.1875" height="18.399999618530273">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">alpha</div>
              </foreignObject>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g class="node default" id="flowchart-b-15" transform="translate(171.25500106811523,25.360000610351562)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <rect rx="0" ry="0" x="-25.985000610351562" y="-17.360000133514404" width="51.970001220703125" height="34.72000026702881" class="label-container"/>
          <g class="label" transform="translate(0,0)">
            <g transform="translate(-15.985000610351562,-7.360000133514404)">
              <foreignObject width="39.962501525878906" height="18.399999618530273">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">bravo</div>
              </foreignObject>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g class="node default" id="flowchart-c-16" transform="translate(312.88000106811523,25.360000610351562)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <rect rx="0" ry="0" x="-29.719999313354492" y="-17.360000133514404" width="59.439998626708984" height="34.72000026702881" class="label-container"/>
          <g class="label" transform="translate(0,0)">
            <g transform="translate(-19.719999313354492,-7.360000133514404)">
              <foreignObject width="49.29999923706055" height="18.399999618530273">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">charlie</div>
              </foreignObject>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <filter id="mermaid-access-highlight-primary">
    <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" flood-color="red"/>
  </filter>
  <filter id="mermaid-access-highlight-secondary">
    <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" flood-color="cyan"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is your path actually just a horizontal or vertical line? Please add a [mcve] to the question with your path.

Answer (score 4):

As the OP comments:

> for my use case it is necessary to dynamically highlight different
> parts of the SVG as the user interacts with the application

Maybe so?

When you hover over different parts of the application, they are highlighted and a shadow is added.

In addition, hints have been added that appear when hovering over different parts of the SVG.

```
<a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> 
        <title> All javascript questions </title>
      <path id="s2"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 90.35 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 105 Z"/>
     </a>
```

Added working links on which there is a transition to various sections of stackoverflow.

Please read the comments to help you understand the main points of the solution.

```css
svg {
  height: 330px;
  width: 330px;
  --d:dodgerblue;
  --r:red;
  --g:yellowgreen;
}

#spot {
  fill:white;
  pointer-events:none;
  }
 #arrow {
 fill:none;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2;
 pointer-events:none;
 } 

#center {
fill:#797979;
stroke:#FFFFFF;
stroke-width:3;
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;

} 
#center:hover {
fill: var(--g);
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}

#s1,#s3, #s5, #s7 {
fill:#3A3A3A;
cursor: pointer; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#s2,#s4,#s6,#s8 {
fill:#797979;
cursor: pointer; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}


#s1:hover, #s3:hover, #s5:hover, #s7:hover  {
 fill: var(--d);
 filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
#s2:hover, #s4:hover, #s6:hover, #s8:hover  {
 fill: var(--r);
 filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox='0 0 110 110'> 
    <defs>  
     <!-- Hover Drop Shadow Filter -->
<filter id="drop-shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" height="130%" width="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/> 
      <feOffset dx="1" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs> 
  <!-- Circle segments with work links Click -->
<g transform="rotate(-22.5 55 55)" >
<a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions"> 
    <title> All questions </title>
  <path id="s1"  d="M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 90.35 Z"/>
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> 
        <title> All javascript questions </title>
      <path id="s2"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 90.35 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 105 Z"/>
     </a> 
    
<a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">
    <title> All SVG Questions </title>
<path id="s3"  d="M 55 55 L 55 105 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.6447 90.35 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css"> 
       <title> All CSS Questions </title>
    <path id="s4"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 90.353 A 50 50 0 0 1 5 55 Z" />
    </a>
<a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java"> 
     <title> All java questions</title>
<path id="s5"  d="M 55 55 L 5 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 19.64 19.64 Z" />
</a> 
    <a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">
       <title> All python questions </title>
    <path id="s6"  d="M 55 55 L 19.64 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 55 5 Z" />
    </a> 
<a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/help"> 
     <title> Reference section </title> 
<path id="s7"  d="M 55 55 L 55 5 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.35 19.64 Z" />
</a>
    <a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php"> 
        <title> All php questions  </title>
    <path id="s8"  d="M 55 55 L 90.35 19.64 A 50 50 0 0 1 105 55 Z" />
    </a>
</g>  
      <a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html"> 
        <title> All HTML questions </title> 
     
  <circle id="center" cx='55' cy='55' r='17'  /> 
  </a>
      <!-- White circles -->
    <circle id="spot" cx='31' cy='31' r='6'   />  
     <use xlink:href="#spot" transform="rotate(90 55 55)" /> 
         <use xlink:href="#spot" transform="rotate(-90 55 55)" />
          <use xlink:href="#spot" transform="rotate(180 55 55)" />
  <!--White arrows --> 
    <polyline id="arrow" points = "46,21 55,12 64,21" fill="none" stroke="white" />   
       <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="rotate(90 55 55)" /> 
         <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="rotate(-90 55 55)" />
          <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="rotate(180 55 55)" />
      
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! unfortunately, although your solution works for the code snippet you provided, it seems to cause the same problem as the filter I am using to achieve the same. I edited my question to add the svg code I am working with.

Answer (score 2):

This **is** the code from Alexander_TT his great answer.

I just wrapped it in a Custom Element (supported in all modern browsers) because it is a great example where SVG and Custom Elements are a good mix.

```html
<svg-navigator colors="gold,goldenrod">
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
    <defs><filter id='drop-shadow' x='-20%' y='-20%' height='130%' width='130%'>
        <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='2' />
        <feOffset dx='1' dy='0' result='offsetblur' />
        <feMerge><feMergeNode /><feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic' /></feMerge>
      </filter></defs>
    <g><!-- The <svg-navigator> Custom Element replaces all these A tags -->
      <a href="">All questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/javascript">All JavaScript questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/css">All CSS questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/javascript">All SVG questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/web+components">All Web Components questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/custom+elements">All Custom Elements questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/javascript+template">All Template questions</a>
      <a href="/tagged/shadowDOM">All shadowDOM questions</a>
    </g>
    <circle id='center' fill='#696969' stroke='white' stroke-width='3' cx='55' cy='55' r='17' />
  </svg>
</svg-navigator>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-navigator", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let colors = this.getAttribute("colors").split `,`;
      let pointers = ["<circle cx='90' cy='70' r='6' fill='white'/>",
                      "<polyline points='90,60 95,70 85,75' fill='white'/>"];
      setTimeout(() => // make sure DOM can be read
        this.querySelector('G')
          .innerHTML = [...this.querySelectorAll("A")].map((node, idx) =>
            `<g transform='rotate(${idx*45-22.5} 55 55)'>` +
            `<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions${node.href}''><title>${node.innerHTML}</title>` +
            `<path fill='${colors[idx%2]}' id='s${idx+1}' d='M 55 55 L 105 55 A 50 50 0 0 1 90.5 90.5z'/>` +
            `</a>${pointers[idx % 2]}</g>` // return segment
          ).join ``)}})

</script>

<style>
  svg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    --d: dodgerblue;
    --r: red;
    --g: yellowgreen;
  }
  svg path,
  #center {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
  }
  #center:hover {
    fill: var(--g);
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
  }
  #s1:hover,
  #s3:hover,
  #s5:hover,
  #s7:hover {
    fill: var(--d);
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
  }

  #s2:hover,
  #s4:hover,
  #s6:hover,
  #s8:hover {
    fill: var(--r);
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular CSS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()

But it is applied to all elements inside the SVG, you can't target just one SVG element.

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>
  <path d='M7 15h2v-2h-2v2zm1-14a4 4 90 00-4 4h2c0-1 1-2 2-2s2 1 2 2c0 2-3 2-3 6h2c0-3 3-3 3-6a4 4 90 00-4-4z'/>
</svg>

<style>
  svg {
    width: 200px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px red);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but for my use case it is necessary to dynamically highlight  different parts of the SVG as the user interacts with the application.

Comment: Firefox will apply CSS filters to individual SVG elements, it's just Chrome (and maybe Safari) that won't.